# How to merge all audio tracks into one

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried everything I could find on the internet but the only real result I got is getting both tracks to be in the final MP4 by using `ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -c:v h264 -c:a mp3 -map 0 -ss 00:59 "../video.mp4"`.

What I want is take the two audio tracks in my input file and merge them into a single one in the output file.

Comment: See "Mixing/combining two audio inputs into one" in dupe link: `ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -c:v h264 -c:a aac -ss 00:59 -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge=inputs=2" -ac 2 "../video.mp4"`

Comment: @llogan nice! that's what I was looking for, I knew about amerge filter but didn't know how to get two tracks from the same file, it's ```[0:a:0][0:a:1]```, it makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!